# Multiple VirtualBox instances

Tags: virtualbox

Can you tell me why one can start multiple VirtualBox Control instances? It should be a **mutex** program, yet I clicked it 12 times and I now have 12 VirtualBox instances.

What does it mean? I can run the **same machine** multiple times? Why isn't it mutex?

Comment: What do you mean by "VirtualBox Control Instances"?  Do you mean the UI that you use to start, stop and configure VMs?

Comment: Yes, I meant that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I'd recommend reading through the [Technical Background](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html) section of the VirtualBox manual.

In summary, VirtualBox uses a client-server type archictecture implemented on top of [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)(or [XPCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPCOM)).  There is a server component (`VBoxSVC` in the manual) which is the main process that handles actually starting and stoping the VMs, as well as managing which clients can access the VMs.  Each instance of the GUI is a client that connects to the server and makes calls on the server objects.  This architecture allows for many different frontends (for example the GUI, command line client or web based client) to manage VMs.

Note also, that there are times when a certain client can take an exclusive lock on a machine and prevent other clients from modifying the VM, but the server component manages those locks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, you *won't* be able to run more than once instance of a single virtual machine. Try it, it won't work.

As you observed yourself, you can have multiple instances of the VirtualBox GUI open. It's by design and I see *heavyd* has just explained it perfectly!